# Loop through all the files with .txt extension in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to loop over files in a folder and test for .txt extensions.
But I get the following error: "awk: cannot open = (No such file or directory)

Here's my code:

```
!/bin/bash

files=$(ls);
for file in $files
  do
  # extension=$($file | awk -F . '{ print $NF }');
  if [ $file | awk -F . "{ print $NF }" = txt ]
    then
      echo $file;
    else
      echo "Not a .txt file";
  fi;
done;
```

Comment: Can't you just use globbing with `for i in *.txt; do ... done` ?

Comment: @oliv, but first I have to list all of the files in the folder I am in? Right?

Comment: @oliv, your solution works. Thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The way you are doing this is wrong in many ways.

1. You should never parse output of `ls`. It does not handle the filename containing special characters intuitively See [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)
2. Don't use variables to store multi-line data. The output of `ls` in a variable is expected to undergo word splitting. In your case `files` is being referenced as a plain variable, and without a delimiter set, you can't go through the multiple files stored.
3. Using `awk` is absolutely unnecessary here, the part `$file | awk -F . "{ print $NF }" = txt` is totally wrong, you are not passing the name the `file` to the pipe, just the variable `$file`, it should have been `echo "$file"`
4. The right interpreter she-bang should have been set as `#!/bin/bash` in your script if you were planning to run it as an executable, i.e. `./script.sh`. The more recommended way would be to say `#!/usr/bin/env bash` to let the shell identify the default version of the `bash` installed.

As such your requirement could be simply reduced to

```
for file in *.txt; do
    [ -f "$file" ] || continue
    echo "$file"
done
```

This is a simple example using a glob pattern using `*.txt` which does pathname expansion on the all the files ending with the `txt` format. Before the loop is processed, the glob is expanded as the list of files i.e. assuming the folder has files as `1.txt`, `2.txt` and `foo.txt`, the loop is generated to

```
for file in 1.txt 2.txt foo.txt; do
```

Even in the presence of no files, i.e. when the glob matches empty (no text files found), the condition `[ -f "$file" ] || continue` would ensure the loop is exit gracefully by checking if the glob returned any valid file results or just an un-expanded string. The condition `[ -f "$file" ]` would fail for everything if except a valid file argument.

Or if you are targeting scripts for bourne again shell, enable glob options to remove non-matching globs, rather than preserving them

```
shopt -s nullglob
for file in *.txt; do
    echo "$file"
done
```

Another way using shell array to store the glob results and parse them over later to do a specific action on them. This way is useful when doing a list of files as an argument list to another command. Using a proper quoted expansion `"${filesList[@]}"` will preserve the spacing/tabs/newlines and other meta characters in filenames.

```
shopt -s nullglob
filesList=(*.txt)

for file in "${filesList[@]}"; do
    echo "$file"
done
```